# Qt include files

Tags: c++, qt, include

I got into a discussion with somebody that tells me that it's not good to do what Qt does with include files because i adopted the same strategy in my code.

Let's use QApplication as an example, when you want to include QApplication then you should do:

```
#include <QApplication>
```

QApplication is a file without extension that contains:

```
#include "qapplication.h"
```

The only disadvantage is see is that it creates more files in the project. Besides that i think it only has advantages.

So my question is, why is this a good or a bad idea?

Comment: The convention was borrowed from the Standard Library. E.g. to include the header defining the class `map` you do `#include <map>`. So, to include the header defining `QApplication` you do `#include <QApplication>`. The reason for the indirect jump is merely an implementation detail (allowing f.i. to do `#include <Foo>` where `Foo` gets defined in `bar.h`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is the matter of personal taste, mostly. Different projects use different style. Qt picked up this style.

1) It is basically partially matching the standard library includes without the header extension, although CamelCase. It is different in that regard though that the standard library does not allow these days to use the suffixed version.

2) It could also help with class includes within a header with a different main class. See this example:

```
#include <QFoo>
```

where QFoo is defined in qbar.h since the main class is QBar, but there is another class put into the same header.

> The only disadvantage is see is that it creates more files in the project.

It does not create more files than needed because these could be generated on the fly like in the Qt Project. In that case, it does not clutter your source tree, and will be put into the build directory, or at least a separate place where it does not get in your way. This is done currently by *syncqt* in the Qt Project.

Comment: My second point is probably red-herring as you could also make qfoo.h include qbar.h, so I think the first point is the gist. Although, on a second thought, it is actually valid, not red-herring IMHO because the QFoo pattern is more like class based, where the foo.h is file based. It would look strange to make qfoo.h include qbar.h and then you include qfoo.h as that would assume a separate file for qfoo as opposed to the class based pattern.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I didn't know that they could be generated with syncqt, i'll have to check that out.

Comment: @fonZ: syncqt is not a public, but internal tool for Qt. It is also written in perl (yuck!), but you can easily crack something together like I did in QtSerialPort: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport/source/c711f3870605d58218e0ca9a52a7aac296ecd396:src/serialport/qt4support/install-helper.pri#L6

Comment: yea i was thinking of something similar with a separate pri file that i include in the pro file.

Answer (score 2):

Using header files with no extension is not a good idea as it makes it difficult to search header files (*.h or *.hpp) and it makes it more difficult to identify the contents of a file (for example if your editor relies on the extension to choose the proper syntax highlighting mode). Also it causes to have more files in the project as you mentioned.

Also Qt uses that convention exactly because smart programmers don't. It means your headers won't clash with new Qt headers.

So i think using your header files with extensions separates your custom header files from Qt ones in some way. It makes it more clear and clean that which header is for Qt and which one is yours.

Comment: As for the last part, note that if you use another dependency which follows the foo.h style, that argument does not weight that much anymore because you need to pick up either of those. :) For instance, QtSerialPort followed the Qt style even without belonging to the Qt Project. Why do you think smart programmers do not use the <foo> style instead of <foo.h>? The standard library along with some other projects use that style. I agree with the first paragraph though.

Comment: @LaszloPapp You are right, many projects use that standard. But i think using headr files with extensions is more straightforward and as i said makes code more clear. Although it is just my personal opinion.

Comment: Yes, I agree that there are header files with extension underneath. I was just referring to the "wrapper include". I do not think anyone debates the internal "qfoo.h", but the point of the "QFoo" wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nejat. I think that Laszlo is right when he says it doesnt matter to use the wrapper include, it makes the code cleaner and easier to read and that is smart in my opinion as code should be readable above all.